# MySql get recommended people to follow

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join, database-design

I want to get a list of friends that have been recommended to me based on the number of mutual friends we have.

Here's my schema:

I have a `users` table, which has a one to many relationship with the `follow_users` table.

```
follow_users {
    'follower_id', //many to one with users
    'followee_id', //many to one with users
    'is_approved'
}
```

How can I write a query that selects the users that have as many mutual friends as I do?

---

**EDIT**

I think I'm getting closer. I've wrote this query

```
$q = $this->em->createQuery("
        select recUser, count(recUser.id) as recUserCount
        from Zgh\FEBundle\Entity\User recUser
            inner join recUser.followees recFollowUser
            where recFollowUser.follower in (
                select mutual.id
                from Zgh\FEBundle\Entity\FollowUsers currentFollowUser
                inner join currentFollowUser.followee mutual
                where currentFollowUser.follower = :user
            )
        group by recUser.id
        order by recUserCount desc
    ");
```

Which returns the users I want, But also returns users that I've already followed, how to exclude already followed users ? 
(I've tried adding `and recFollowUser.follower != :user` just after the `where` statement but no good)

Comment: @rontornambe I really can't get my head around it. I was thinking about getting the friends of friends but don't know how to order them by mutual friends.

Comment: It maybe useful for you to create an SQLFiddle where you can define the table structures and  add some data. This will help you visualize you proble more clearly and allow us to help more effectively.

Comment: @rontornambe I've edited my question. Please take a look at it.

Comment: What is the framework your attempted query is written in?

Comment: What fact is expressed by a row in this table in terms of follower_id, followee_id and is_approved? And what does this have to do with recommendations? And you want friends that have been recommended to you, but what does "based on" mean? It implies there's a criterion but you didn't actually _give_ it. Make the effort to use words to clearly say what you want. Eg, you want users and counts where the count is the number of friends that have been recommended to you?

Answer (score 1):

This query will get user id's of friends of friends that a given `:user_id` has not friended yet. The list is ordered by # of mutual friends.

```
SELECT fu2.follower_id
FROM follow_users fu
JOIN follow_users fu2
    ON fu2.followee_id = fu.follower_id
    AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM follow_users fu3 
        WHERE fu3.followee_id = :user_id
        AND fu3.follower_id = fu2.follower_id)
WHERE fu.followee_id = :user_id
GROUP BY fu2.follower_id
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
```

Comment: First of all thanks for your help, I've kinda solved it, but I'm facing some problem. Please check my edit in the question. I've tried the `NOT EXISTS` but no good either.

Comment: @RafaelAdel try `MEMBER OF` something along the lines of `AND mutual NOT MEMBER OF myUser.followers`

Comment: This doesn't work for me. It just returns the id of the person I'm trying to find recommendations for.